# Filter pandas dataframe using combination of id and before a certain datetime (by id)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following, with ids, timestamps where an observation was made, and a check for a certain condition (and other information):

```
id     ds                      condYN     otherinfo    
 1      2146-06-03 13:41:00     Y          blah
 1      2151-11-24 01:39:00     Y          etc
 2      2147-06-05 15:59:00     Y          etc
 3      2194-06-13 18:39:00     N          etc
 3      2196-09-27 18:21:00     Y          etc
 3      2196-10-27 12:20:00     Y          etc
 4      2196-11-27 11:20:00     N          etc
```

I want to filter the dataset such that only people (identified by id) that have had the condition (condYN = "Y") are listed, with all observations up to and including the first observation of the condition listed:

```
id     ds                      condYN     otherinfo    
 1      2146-06-03 13:41:00     Y          blah
 2      2147-06-05 15:59:00     Y          etc
 3      2194-06-13 18:39:00     N          etc
 3      2196-09-27 18:21:00     Y          etc
```

I have a list of tuples, by ID and datestamp of first time the condition was found, for each person):

```
[(1,2146-06-03 13:41:00),(2,2147-06-05 15:59:00),(3,2196-09-27 18:21:00)]
```

But am unsure how to do such a filter on the dataset (matches the first item, <= the second item).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `pd.Series` from your list of tuples, with ids as index and dates as values. Then `map` the id column of your original dataframe with this series and compare to the ds column. Use this mask in a `loc` to select the wanted rows.

```
l = [(1,'2146-06-03 13:41:00'),(2,'2147-06-05 15:59:00'),(3,'2196-09-27 18:21:00')]

s = pd.Series(map(lambda x: x[1], l), map(lambda x: x[0], l))
print(s)
# 1    2146-06-03 13:41:00
# 2    2147-06-05 15:59:00
# 3    2196-09-27 18:21:00
# dtype: object

res = df.loc[df['ds']<=df['id'].map(s)]
print(res)
#    id                  ds condYN otherinfo
# 0   1 2146-06-03 13:41:00      Y      blah
# 2   2 2147-06-05 15:59:00      Y       etc
# 3   3 2194-06-13 18:39:00      N       etc
# 4   3 2196-09-27 18:21:00      Y       etc
```